# restore data on external disk after windows repair

Tags: windows, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

Here is an issue my friend faced:
He has an external hard drive NTFS formatted. First he was putting photos to it using MacBook. Then he was putting photos using Ubuntu laptop. Then he moved to a Windows laptop. And once the hard drive was connected to the Windows laptop, Windows proposed to scan and repair the drive. After choosing scan and repair, all the photos that were put there from Ubuntu disappeared.
How to restore the photos?

Comment: Which filesystem?

Comment: @ChanganAuto NTFS

Comment: There are free and commercial apps file recovery in Windows. You may want to try some. And this is a lesson. You need Windows to error correct NTFS, no other OS can do it, and such drive is used with non-Windows OSes and it has logical errors data loss can an frequently happen.

Comment: **N.B.:** First make a backup image of the drive, then operate on the image. Further attempt to recover data from the munged drive is likely to *destroy* more data.

Comment: This -is- a lesson. Don't use NTFS and don't use Windows.

Comment: @mitts that is neither accurate nor helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @musick2myear did you read the bit where windows "helpfully" offered to "scan and repair"...and then all his photos were gone?